# How to use Kernel Regression to predict new data?

Tags: r, regression, matlab, kernel-smoothing

I have climate data for 240 predictors and precipitation flux (as the target variable) for 3000+ days. I want to use **Gaussian kernel regression** to predict the precipitation flux for the next 2000+ days.

I have gone through some of the available packages in both `R` and `MatLab`.

`R` has the `np` package which provides the `npreg()` to perform kernel regression. However, the documentation for this package does not tell me how I can use the model derived to predict new data.

Similarly, MatLab has the codes provided by **Yi Cao** ([ksrmv.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19279-multivariant-kernel-regression-and-smoothing)) and **Youngmok Yun** ([gaussian_kern_reg.m](http://youngmok.com/gaussian-kernel-regression-for-multidimensional-feature-with-matlab-code/)). Here as well, I am unable to understand how to use the model obtained to predict the new data.

I would be very grateful if someone can explain to me how to perform prediction using any one of these methods.

Comment: For `ksrmv.m`, the documentation comment says: `r=ksrmv(x,y,h,z) calculates the regression at location z (default z=x).` So `x` is your training data, `y` their labels, `h` the bandwidth, and `z` the test data. For `gaussian_kern_reg.m`, you call `gaussian_kern_reg(xs, x, y, h)`; `xs` are the test points. For `npreg`, the argument to use for the test data is `newdata` (which it calls "evaluation data": the points where you're evaluating the model).

Comment: For `npreg` you can use `predict` to get eval at data. As an example: `predict(your_npreg_result, newdata = data.frame_of_new_data)`

Comment: The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/vignettes/np.pdf) of `np` at pag. 11 tells you how to make predictions